# How do ls file names in numerical order that have space characters in the filename

Tags: shell-script, ls, sort

Hi I have the following files, whose names contain spaces, on a Linux machine.
I need to `ls` them in numerical order

```
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_1.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_2.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_3.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_4.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_5.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_10.csv
```

When I try ls -1 -- *.csv | sort -n or ls-lart the _10 file is always sorted first.
How do ls and sort these in the correct numerical order with _10.csv at the bottom?

```
ls -1 -- *.csv | sort -n

myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_10.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_1.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_2.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_3.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_4.csv
myfile_2020-Jul-06 00-00-00_5.csv
```

Comment: Try `sort -t_ -k3,3n` to sort numerically by the 3rd field of underscore-separated records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this option for GNU ls:

```
ls -v
```

Per man page for ls:

> **-v**     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: Thank you @Sonia! it worked :-)